# Error no compila capistrano yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

alguien sabe por que me sale ese error? De repente salió cada vez que hago deploy con capistrano rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deploy.rb

```
set :application, "*****"
set :stages, "*****"
set :default_stage, '*****'
set :repo_url, "*****"

# Deploy to the user's home directory
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

set :nvm_node, 'v14.17.6'
set :nvm_map_bins, %w{node yarn webpack rake}
set :nvm_roles, :all
set :yarn_roles, :all

set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true

set :init_system, :systemd
set :service_unit_name, "sidekiq.service"

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Only keep the last 5 releases to save disk space
set :keep_releases, 5
```

Perdonen la censura, no quiero comprometer la seguridad de mi servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví agregando mas memoria swap...